# Reactjs, How to include component that in cloud database?

Tags: reactjs, import, components, include

I'm just learn ReactJS recently, and I need your Help!
I work on a ReactJS project that have Header Content and Footer that store on other database.
So what I doing now is to get that Header, Content and Footer component in to my App.js and compile it.
Is there a way that can get the content in cloud and include it to my reactjs?

I wish it Work like what it look like...

```
import React from 'react';   
import Header from "https://example.com/component/Header.js";

function App() {   
  return (  
    <>  
     <Header/>
    </>  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

a feature of react is that it imports files that are inside your document src
it is

import React from "react";

import Header from "../component/Header";